# Mockito keeps returning a message saying that the parameter is null. Why?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

Test keeps returning a message saying that the attr is null. Why? the attribute is populated from an .yml file

I have a class like this:

```
@Service
public class ClassA {
   private String attr;
   ServiceB serviceB;

   @Inject
   public ClassA (ServiceB serviceB, @Value("${attr.value}") String attr) {
      this.attr = attr;
      this.serviceB = serviceB;
   }

   public void methodX() {

      try {
          serviceB.process(attr);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          log.error("Error running ", e);
      }
   }
 }
```

The test method is like this:

```
@Test
public void testMethodX() throws Exception {

    doNothing().when(serviceB).process(eq("XXX"));

    serviceB.methodX();

    verify(serviceB).process(eq("XXX"));
}
```

But the test keeps returning:

```
Strict stubbing argument mismatch. Please check:
 - this invocation of 'process' method:
    serviceB.process(
    null
);
```

Comment: Have you verified that the population actually works?  Print out the value of `attr`.

Comment: Can you post your full test class?